# android different preferences for contact list from db

Tags: android

I am trying to allow setting different preferences for contacts that are saved in db via `PreferenceScreen`. For that I read that in order to create multiple `SharedPreferences`, one can do something like:

```
SharedPreferences prefContact1 = getSharedPreferences("micheal", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences prefContact2 = getSharedPreferences("john", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences prefContact3 = getSharedPreferences("frady", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// and so on
```

And so I am creating different preferences like above here:

```
// create contact-based pref

String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("phone"));
user_preference = getSharedPreferences(phone, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// start contact pref screen / activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactSettingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("phone", phone);

startActivity(intent);
```

And On `ContactSettingActivity`, I have this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String phone = intent.getStringExtra("phone");

this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.user_preferences);
this.initSummaries(this.getPreferenceScreen());

// get contact's own pref
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(phone, MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);   

// ... more code
```

Here is my `user_preferences.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="Notification Settings" >
      <RingtonePreference
          android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
          android:key="user_prefRingtone"
          android:ringtoneType="notification"
          android:showDefault="true"
          android:showSilent="true"
          android:summary="Default ringtone for incoming SMS"
          android:title="SMS Ringtone" />

      <CheckBoxPreference
          android:defaultValue="true"
          android:key="user_prefVibrate"
          android:summary="Vibrate on incoming SMS"
          android:title="Vibrate" >
      </CheckBoxPreference>

      <ListPreference
          android:defaultValue="0"
          android:entries="@array/pref_notif_icon_entries"
          android:entryValues="@array/pref_notif_icon_values"
          android:key="user_prefnotificon"
          android:summary="Change the notification area icon"
          android:title="Notification Icon" />
      <ListPreference
          android:defaultValue="Off"
          android:entries="@array/pref_led_color_entries"
          android:entryValues="@array/pref_led_color_values"
          android:key="user_prefled"
          android:summary="Color of the LED"
          android:title="LED Color" />

      <CheckBoxPreference
          android:defaultValue="true"
          android:key="user_prefWakeup"
          android:summary="Wakeup screen on incoming SMS"
          android:title="Screen Wakup" >
      </CheckBoxPreference>
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now problem is that even though I am setting different preferences based on contact's phone via `getSharedPreferences(phone, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` but still when I go to any user's preference screen, it is always the same settings applied to all contacts :(

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or how to set different preferences for items (contacts) of ListView so that each one will have different notification sound, notification icon etc for example ? Or any other approach that works is also welcome :)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it, I added below line to settings activity:

```
this.getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(phone);
```

here is updated code:

```
public class ContactSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String phone = intent.getStringExtra("phone");

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(phone, MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(phone);
        this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.user_preferences);
        this.initSummaries(this.getPreferenceScreen());
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
```